# Data is available in .map() but not in .subscribe() - angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, rxjs, angular-material

I am working on an angular 5 code. I have made an API call in serviceA as

```
public functionA{
  let url ='someURL'
  let body ={some params}
 return this.http.post(url, body).map((res: any) => {
           const data = res;

     }
}
```

and I am able to get the data here.

Now i need the same data in another componentB. and i subscribed to the function as follows:

```
this.serviceA.functionA.subscribe(data=> console.log(data));
```

But here in component B , I am not able to get the data. it is undefined.

Im on angular version 5.2. Could someone please let me know on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your map callback _doesn't return anything_.

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning anything, the map should return the result of the callback function.

I think this will solve the problem:

```
public functionA{
  let url ='someURL'
  let body ={some params}
 return this.http.post(url, body).map((res: any) => {
        const data = res;
        return data;  
     }
}
```